# ASP.NET Literal control dissapears from auto generated designer.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a strange problem. After I add a literal control to a web form all is well as Visual Studio also adds a declaration to auto generated designer.cs file and I can access literal control in code behind file.

I also need to pass the value of this literal control to a JavaScript function and I need to wrap this asp:Listeral control in single quotes. As soon as I do that Visual Studio removes it form the design code. What can I do to stop Visual Studio from removing the declaration or is there a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve.

```
<button class="submitBtn" onclick="javascript:JsUtils.submit_answer('<%#Eval('QuestionID')%>,'<asp:Literal ID='testResultId' runat='server'></asp:Literal>');">Submit Answer</button>
```

Comment: It disappears because the control no longer exists. You are creating a string containing "<asp:Literal ID='testResultId' runat='server'></asp:Literal>". I suspect there is a better way, why is it being passed to submit_answer(), is it used to output a result?

Comment: submit_answer function will do an Ajax post request with the supplied arguments. The literal is being set in code behind by a value from a data access class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the *most basic level* you probably want to do something like this instead:

```
<asp:Literal ID='testResultId' runat='server'></asp:Literal>
<button class="submitBtn"
onclick="javascript:JsUtils.submit_answer('<%#Eval('QuestionID')%>,
'<%=testResultID.Text%>');">Submit Answer</button>
```

However this probably is far from ideal. You say the literal value is "set in code behind" - why? It will be displayed on the screen, if you are only trying to pass data from server to client via this function, then why render it at all, just to reference it again to create this function call? Just add it directly to your function, e.g. something like this:

```
<button class="submitBtn"
onclick="javascript:JsUtils.submit_answer('<%#Eval('QuestionID')%>,
'<%=SomeProperty%>');">Submit Answer</button>
```

where `SomeProperty` is a string property of your page that returns the value you are setting to that literal.